# How to randomize spell scrolls

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, treasure

In 5th edition when a scroll comes up for loot, or when rolling for a robe of useful items, how do you pick which spell is on the scroll? I can't find a table for it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simple answer is that you don't need a table .  Here are a couple of ways I have done it.

1. Choose spells (or multiple spells) that you are sure a party spell caster will need or use, or perhaps one that a party Wizard is looking for to copy into his spell book.
2. Draw them at random from the spell list for a given class and spell level, then roll.  Whatever the dice decide is the spell.

   As an example for point 2: there are 22 spells in the 2d level Bard list.  Assign them numbers 1-22. Roll a d12 and a d6.  1-3 on the d6 is for spells numbered 1-11 when you roll the d12, 4-6 on the d6 indicates spells numbered 12-22.  Any roll of a 12 on the d12 is rolled over.  If your rolled 9 and 2, respectively, you'd get Heat Metal as the spell on the scroll.  If you rolled 11 and 5, you'd get Zone of Truth. .

I prefer option 1 as a DM, but have used option 2.